# Does the Juniper SRX have spanning-tree capabilities?

Tags: juniper-junos, spanning-tree, juniper-srx

I can't find any documentation supporting spanning-tree capabilities on SRX devices. I'm running a virtual image, which I thought was more-or-less the vSRX:

```
root> show version           
Model: firefly-perimeter
JUNOS Software Release [12.1X47-D20.7]
```

But no commands like `show spanning-tree bridge` are available. So either (a) I have the wrong virtual image, or (b) the SRX doesn't support spanning-tree features, which I kind of find hard to believe?

... or (c) I just don't know what command I *really* want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vSRX doesn't support switching features, so the answer is:

> (b) the SRX doesn't support spanning-tree features.

vSRX is designed to be a virtual firewall, therefore it doesn't need "switching". It's only the physical SRX devices, that support switching. 
Take a look at [this product datasheet from Juniper](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/firefly12.1x47/information-products/topic-collections/firefly-perimeter/12.1X47/firefly-perimeter-release-notes.pdf), it lists all of the available features on that platform.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if an image exists to mimic a physical SRX?

Comment: There is no official image, but you can find guides on how to create an "Olive" image.